# node to traverse cannot be null?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

i already saw the possible fixes to this problem, but i don't know what can i change in  my code.

```
package br.com.caelum.livraria.dao;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.caelum.livraria.modelo.Usuario;

@Stateless
public class UsuarioDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Usuario buscaPeloLogin(String login) {
        TypedQuery<Usuario> usuarioQuery = manager.createQuery("select u from Usuario u where u.login = :username",Usuario.class);
        usuarioQuery.setParameter("username", login);
        return usuarioQuery.getSingleResult();
    }   
}
```

Comment: And neither do we since you don't bother posting the entity, exception and stack trace ...

Comment: `select u.<* or a table column here> from Usuario u where u.login = :username`

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!

I Just put "LIKE" operator instead "=".